How to download a file only if it is missing or its URL has changed?
Similar to this question how can you write a Makefile to download a file if it is missing OR if the URL you are downloading it from changes.
I think the way to do this is to have a rule that always runs that writes the URL to a stamp file, but only if it is different, or something like that. But I can't quite figure it out.

Your suggestion makes a lot of sense.  Obtain the URL from a file, and use that file as a dependency:
# Untested
%: %.url
    wget -O $@ $(shell cat $<)
    touch $@


Ah interesting idea. I was imagining that the URL would be specified in the Makefile and then written to the .url file only if it is different, but maybe it's easier just to have the user specify it in that file directly instead.

If the URL is a Makefile variable, I don't see an easy way to make a dependency on it rather than on the whole Makefile.  It could be done, but would be very complex and hard to reason about.  Making a separate URL file for each downloaded file is IMO clearer and perhaps more tractable when inspecting source-control history, too.

I think you could - you somehow need a rule that always runs... but I couldn't figure it out and I think your solution is much simpler so I'm going with that.

If the rule always runs, then every rule that depends on the file will always run too - I couldn't see any way around that.

Make will only build targets if they don't exist, or one of its prerequisites has a newer modification time.  If a prerequisite's recipe runs but does not change the prerequisite's modification time, then the target will not run (this assumes you're using normal targets not .PHONY targets of course).  So, to avoid rebuilding all the targets that depend on a prerequisite, you make your prerequisite's recipe smart enough to not update the prerequisite's mod time unless it's really changed (whatever that means).

@MadScientist does it actually re-check the mtime though? Or does it assume "well I had to run the recipe to rebuild the foo file and bar depends on that so I have to rebuild bar"?

I'd always believed the latter, but I know that @MadScientist's knowledge of Make exceeds mine, so I'm probably wrong.

It rechecks.  It has to: the idiom "generate a temp file; cmp with the old file; rename temp to $@ only if different" has been a critical part of makefiles (including all the standard makefiles generated by autotools) since forever.
